# throw new assert.AssertionError in NodeJS with SOAP

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I be using SOAP module in my project of nodeJs to consume a soap web service like a client. This is my file:

```
var soap = require('soap');

this.getSoap = function (request, response) {
var url = 'http://rhoda.uci.cu/roa.php/interoperability/session?wsdl';
var args = {};

soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        client.createAnonymousSession(args, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log(result)
            }
        });
    }
  });
};
```

**createAnonymousSession** is a function available in the web service and return a number of anonymoussession (example: 5550a505b5d86).

When I execute obtain this error:

assert.js:92

throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
  AssertionError: invalid message definition for rpc style binding
    at Client._invoke (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/soap/lib/client.js:183:12)
    at null.createAnonymousSession (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/soap/lib/client.js:129:10)
    at /home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/src/SoapModule/controller/soapController.js:23:20
    at /home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/soap/lib/soap.js:49:5
    at null.callback (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/soap/lib/soap.js:36:7)
    at /home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1056:12
    at WSDL._processNextInclude (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1098:12)
    at WSDL.processIncludes (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1131:8)
    at /home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/soap/lib/wsdl.js:1011:10
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)

Answer (score 0):

Well my solution:

```
var soap = require('soap');

this.getSoap = function (request, response) {
var url = 'http://rhoda.uci.cu/roa.php/interoperability/session?wsdl';

soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
    console.log(client.describe());
    client.createAnonymousSession(null, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(result)
        }
    });
  });
};
```

When the web service function **not require a args**, then is **null**.